# Left Shift key not working properly

Tags: keyboard

After reinstallation, my left <kbd>shift</kbd> key has the same behavior as the <kbd>option</kbd> key. Is there any setup to disable that? I mention that right <kbd>shift</kbd> key is working properly.

Thank you!

Comment: Test for hardware fail using another keyboard. There is no system option to make left & right shift behave differently.

Answer (score -1):

you may try this.
click start - settings - select Ease of Access - select Keyboard - Turn off Filter keys and Turn off Sticky keys.

maby this can work

Comment: Isn't the "Start" button a Windows/PC thing? This site is for Apple products.