# Left shift key acts as if option key is pressed as well

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

When I press the left shift key on my machine, it behaves as if both the option and shift keys are pressed.

So a becomes Å, k becomes , h becomes Ó and so on.

The shift key isn't able to be remapped in system settings. Is there a way to change this behavior back?

Edit:

The right shift key works normally.

Sticky keys isn't enabled. When enabled, it shows the issue clearly.

The left alt key is also turns on shift. The right alt key works normally.

Other keyboards behave normally.

Comment: Can you reproduce with another keyboard? Could be a hardware issue?

Comment: Does the right shift key work correctly? Have you tried another keyboard? Is it the same?

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/417883/left-shift-key-not-working-properly?